# Using array.length in calculations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to figure out if this is possible, in javascript

I have an array of objects called cart that contains product.quantity and i want to use the value of cart.length in a calculation but i keep getting NaN, even though the type is a number. Can anyone assist please.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
$scope.getCartTotals = function() {
  var totalInCart = 0;

  cartCount = $scope.cart.length;
  $scope.cart.forEach(function(product) {
    totalInCart += cartCount * product.quantity;
  });

  return totalInCart;
};
```

```html
<body ng-controller="StoreController">
  <div ng-show="cart.length > 0">{{getCartTotals()}}</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Tyr to initialize `totalInCart`. Ie: `var totalInCart = 0`

Comment: i have  thanks, have refactored the code again, will post, still not achieving the desired result though

Comment: Can you post your html code as well? How do you call your `$scope.getCartTotals()` method? Have you tried setup breakpoints and check the values?

Answer (score 3):

You're adding to `undefined`, which makes `NaN`. You should initialize `totalInCart` to `0`:

```
var total = 0,
    cartCount = $scope.cart.length,
    totalInCart = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-show` here, this will call the method `getCartTotals` for each and every value of `cart.length`.

`ng-show` just hide/displays by toggling css but `ng-if` will not render the HTML if condition is false and hence no execution of `getCartTotals`

So you can either use `ng-if` or you can just make the null/undefined checks in `getCartTotals` method for `cart.length` and `product.quantity`

Comment: Thanks, that helps with not showing the element if 0 but calculation is more my issue

Comment: Gr8. You can just upvote if the answer helped you whenever you have sufficient reputations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't have idea about your cart object `structure.According` to information you provided about cart object i have created a demo in plunker. So you can check on below plunker link
    https://plnkr.co/edit/4tYc9UjrzqQXvFJuvW5Y?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it was that i was trying to calculate using the wrong perimeters entirely and had nothing to do with the length of the array so therefore this entire question is now invalid, thanks for all the helpful comments.